# Equivalence relation of atoms

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, equivalence-relations

If $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ is a measure space, a set $A\in\mathcal{S}$ is called an atom of $\mu$ iff $0<\mu(A)<\infty$ and for every $C\subset A$ with $C\in\mathcal{S}$, either $\mu(C)=0$ or $\mu(C)=\mu(A)$.

For two atoms $A$ and $B$, define a relation $A\approx B$ iff $\mu(A\cap B)=\mu(A)$.

For $\mu$ finite, show that $\approx$ is an equivalence relation.

My efforts:

$A\approx A$ since $\mu(A\cap A)=\mu(A)$.

Suppose $A\approx B$. Since $A$ is an atom, $\mu(A)>0$. Since $A\approx B$, $\mu(A\cap B)=\mu(A)>0$. Since $B$ is an atom and $A\cap B\subset B$, either $\mu(A\cap B)=0$ or $\mu(A\cap B)=\mu(B)$. Since $\mu(A\cap B)>0$, we must have $\mu(A\cap B)=\mu(B)$. So $B\approx A$.

Suppose $A\approx B$ and $B\approx C$. We need to show $A\approx C$. Since $C$ is an atom and $A\cap C\subset C$, either $\mu(A\cap C)=0$ or $\mu(A\cap C)=\mu(C)$. We only need to show $\mu(A\cap C)>0$. Assume $\mu(A\cap C)=0$. Then $0<\mu(A)=\mu(A\cap C)+\mu(A\setminus C)=\mu(A\setminus C)$. Since $A\setminus C\subset A\setminus(B\cap C)$, we have $\mu(A\setminus C)\leq\mu(A\setminus (B\cap C))=\mu(A)-\mu(A\cap B\cap C)$.

Then I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Where did you come across this equivalence relation?  Seems interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that $A\approx B$ iff the difference between $A$ and $B$ is negligible (in measure). We do just that: Suppose $A\approx B$ and $B\approx C$.

Notice that
\begin{align*}
A\setminus C
&\subseteq ((A\setminus B)\cup B)\setminus C\\
&=\left[(A\setminus B)\setminus C\right]\cup \left[B\setminus C\right]\\
&\subseteq (A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus C)
\end{align*}
so $\mu(A\setminus C)\leq\mu(A\setminus B)+\mu(B\setminus C)$.

Now we have the decomposition of $A$ as a disjoint union $A=(A\setminus B)\sqcup (A\cap B)$, so from $A\approx B$ we get
$$\mu(A)=\mu(A\setminus B)+\mu(A\cap B)=\mu(A\setminus B)+\mu(A),$$
so $\mu(A\setminus B)=0$. Similarly, from $B\approx C$ you get $\mu(B\setminus C)=0$.

Then
$$0\leq\mu(A\setminus C)\leq\mu(A\setminus B)+\mu(B\setminus C)=0$$
Therefore $\mu(A\setminus C)=0$. Now we decompose $A=(A\setminus C)\sqcup(A\cap C)$ to obtain
$$\mu(A)=\mu(A\setminus C)+\mu(A\cap C)=0+\mu(A\cap C)=\mu(A\cap C),$$
which means that $A\approx C$.

---

So in the end, what I'm doing is using the following lemma (which follows by decomposing $A=(A\setminus B)\cup (A\cap B)$) a few times, which rewrites $\approx$ in terms of differences and makes some computations easier:

> For atoms $A,B$, the following are equivalent:
>
> - $A\approx B$;
> - $\mu(A\setminus B)=0$.

Comment: I came across this equivalence relation in Section 3.5 in Dudley's book Real Analysis and Probability. My only remaining question is: Where is the condition "for $\mu$ finite" used? According to definition, any atom is of finite measure. But according to the author, "for $\mu$ finite" is necessary.

Comment: @JunkWarrior It is not necessary for the measure itself to be finite to be able to speak of atoms. But the measure of the atoms should indeed be finite, otherwise bad things happen. E.g. if we allowed "atoms of infinite measure", take $X=\left\{a,b\right\}$, $\mathcal{S}=\mathcal{P}(X)$ (every set measurable) and $\mu(\varnothing)=0$ and $\mu(A)=\infty$ if $A\neq\varnothing$. Then every nonemtpy set would be an "atom of infinite measure", but the relation $\approx$ would not be transitive: $\{a\}\approx\{a,b\}$ and $\{a,b\}\approx\{b\}$ but not $\{a\}\approx\{b\}$.

Comment: But the definition already said an atom must be of finite measure. So we don't need to worry about atom of infinite measure. It seems to me the author want every member of $\mathcal{S}$ to be of finite measure besides the atoms. This is a step in proving every localizable measure can be decomposed into purely atomic measure and nonatomic measure. The author considers the case of finite $\mu$ first. Then he puts forward this equivalence. Maybe the author forgot that he had required the atom to be of finite measure in the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Use $\mu((A \cap B) \cup (B \cap C)) = \mu(A \cap B) + \mu(B \cap C) - \mu(A \cap B \cap C)$.  $A \cap B \subseteq B$ and $B \cap C \subseteq B$ so $(A \cap B) \cup (B \cap C) \subseteq B$.  By monotonicity,
\begin{equation*}
0 < \mu(A \cap B) \leq \mu((A \cap B) \cup (B \cap C))
\end{equation*}
so $\mu((A \cap B) \cup (B \cup C)) = \mu(A) = \mu(B) = \mu(C)$.  From this, we conclude that $\mu(A \cap B \cap C) = \mu(A) + \mu(A) - \mu(A) = \mu(A)$ and it follows that $\mu(A \cap C) = \mu(A) = \mu(C)$.

Comment: I came across this equivalence relation in Section 3.5 in Dudley's book Real Analysis and Probability. My only remaining question is: Where is the condition "for $\mu$ finite" used? According to definition, any atom is of finite measure. But according to the author, "for $\mu$ finite" is necessary.

Comment: I don't see the need for $\mu$ to be a finite measure.  The very first equality only uses the fact that $(B,\mathcal{S}_{B},\mu)$ is a finite measure space.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it in a different way (each step is justified by the previous one):

1. $\mu(B\cup C)=\mu(B)+\mu(C)-\mu(B\cap C)=\mu(B\cap C)+\mu(C)-\mu(B\cap C)=\mu(C)$
2. $\mu((A\cap B)\cup C)=\mu((A\cup C)\cap(B\cup C))\le\mu(B\cup C)=\mu(C)$
3. $\mu(A\cap B\cap C)=\mu(A\cap B)+\mu(C)-\mu((A\cap B)\cup C)\ge\mu(A\cap B)+\mu(C)-\mu(C)=\mu(A\cap B)=\mu(A)$
4. $\mu(A)\ge\mu(A\cap C)\ge\mu(A\cap B\cap C)\ge\mu(A)\Rightarrow\mu(A\cap C)=\mu(A)$